# Make a VStack height according to content in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, height, geometryreader

I want to make a "card" but the height depends a list of items, I don't how to set a different value according to my sizes list... Example:

**ContentView Struct**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var orderList : [Order] = [
        
        Order(id: 0, productList: [Product(id: 0, name: "itemA", quantity: "24", isEvaluated: true), Product(id: 0, name: "itemB", quantity: "2", isEvaluated: false)]),
        
        Order(id: 1, productList: [Product(id: 0, name: "itemC", quantity: "4", isEvaluated: true), Product(id: 0, name: "itemD", quantity: "12", isEvaluated: false),Product(id: 0, name: "itemE", quantity: "6", isEvaluated: false), Product(id: 0, name: "itemF", quantity: "5", isEvaluated: false)]),
                                   
        Order(id: 2, productList: [Product(id: 0, name: "itemG", quantity: "24", isEvaluated: true)]),
        
        
        Order(id: 3, productList: [Product(id: 0, name: "itemH", quantity: "5", isEvaluated: true), Product(id: 0, name: "itemI", quantity: "2", isEvaluated: false),Product(id: 0, name: "itemJ", quantity: "16", isEvaluated: false), Product(id: 0, name: "itemK", quantity: "4", isEvaluated: false), Product(id: 0, name: "itemL", quantity: "2", isEvaluated: false)]),
        
        Order(id: 4, productList: [Product(id: 0, name: "itemM", quantity: "8", isEvaluated: true)])
    ]
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach(orderList, id: \.self){order in
                ScrollView(showsIndicators: false){
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        Group{
                            HStack{
                                Text("#Order " + "\(order.id)").multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                Spacer()
                                Text("In Progress").multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            }.padding([.bottom],5)
                        }
                        
                        Group{
                            VStack{
                                ForEach(order.productList.indices) { currentIndex in
                                ItemRow(getProduct(productList: order.productList, index: currentIndex))
                                        .padding(.bottom, 5)
                                }
                            }
                        }.padding([.bottom], 10)
                        
                        HStack{
                            Text("Products")
                            Spacer()
                            Text("$00.00")
                        }
                        
                        HStack{
                            Text("Shipping Expenses")
                            Spacer()
                            Text("$00.00")
                        }
                        
                        HStack{
                            Text("Total")
                            Spacer()
                            Text("$0.00")
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
                    .padding(10)
                    
                }
                .background(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2)
                        .fill(Color.white)
                        .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 2, x: 0, y: 2)
                )
                .padding(.bottom, 10)
            }
         }
         .padding(16)
    }
    
    func getProduct(productList: [Product], index: Int)-> Product{
        return productList[index]
    }
}
```

**ItemRow Struct**

```
struct ItemRow: View {
    
    let currentProduct: Product
    
    init(_ currentProduct: Product) {
        self.currentProduct = currentProduct
    }
        
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            HStack{
                Text("• \(currentProduct.name)")
                Spacer()
            }
            HStack{
                Text("quantity \(currentProduct.quantity)")
                Spacer()
            }
            
            if !currentProduct.isEvaluated{
                HStack{
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action:{
                        // do sth
                    }){
                        Text("rate now!")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PS. in itemsList you must create a `struct` called `Order` like this: (Don't mind on hardcode values, I made it to make the example easier)

```
struct Order: Hashable {
    var id: Int
    var productList: [Product]
}
```

PS2. in productList you must create a `struct` called `Product` like this:

```
struct Product: Hashable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var quantity : String
    var isEvaluated : Bool
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want the cards (red frame) to take as much space as they need to display the content they have without the need of scrolling on the card itself?

[image: Before Fix]

Short answer. You don't need to.

SwiftUI does it for you. You only have one small mistake in your code in `ContentView`. Move the `ScrollView` up to the level where you have the `VStack` and remove the `VStack`. You `ContentView` `body` should now look like this:

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        ForEach(orderList, id: \.self){order in
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                Group{
                    HStack{
                        Text("#Order " + "\(order.id)").multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        Spacer()
                        Text("In Progress").multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }.padding([.bottom],5)
                }
                
                Group{
                    VStack{
                        ForEach(order.productList.indices) { currentIndex in
                        ItemRow(getProduct(productList: order.productList, index: currentIndex))
                                .padding(.bottom, 5)
                        }
                    }
                }.padding([.bottom], 10)
                
                HStack{
                    Text("Products")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("$00.00")
                }
                
                HStack{
                    Text("Shipping Expenses")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("$00.00")
                }
                
                HStack{
                    Text("Total")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("$0.00")
                }
                Spacer()
            
            }.background(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2)
                    .fill(Color.white)
                    .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 2, x: 0, y: 2)
            )
            .padding(.bottom, 10)
        }
     }
     .padding(16)
}
```

This gives you the following result:

[image: After Fix]

Comment: Thank you so much!